# Where can I find my Bigquery reservation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-billing

I created a BQ reservation for one of my projects and I see it being billed but I cannot find it in the Capacity Management page.

[image]

I have checked every geographical location as well. I still see it as the main billing item, where it used to be just BigQuery before I made the reservation.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the billing menu of your Billing account, go the Cost Table section. Select the period (current month is fine!) and select the service (only "BigQuery Reservation API")

Your reservation admin project(s) should appear!